# MISSING_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER error with Basic Auth

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am getting this error with trying access to wordpress with Basic Auth.

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": "MISSING_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER",
    "code": "401",
    "error_description": "Authorization header not received. Either authorization header was not sent or it was removed by your server due to security reasons."
}
```

I installed "WordPress REST API Authentication" to enable API Access. I tested, in the plugin test page the access and works.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/cXQz6kz.png]

From postman, I am using this request:

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1/testblog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic dGVzdGJsb2c6dGVzdGJsb2c='
```

User / Pass are: testblog / testblog

This is the server info:

```
Apache Version: 2.4.54.2  
Apache Server Software: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) 
PHP/8.0.26 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev 
Port defined for Apache: 80
PHP Version: [Apache module]  8.0.26 
Loaded PHP extensions Use of PHP versions   [FCGI] 7.4.33 - 8.0.26 - 8.1.13 - 8.2.0 
FCGI mode help MySQL Version: 8.0.31 
Port defined for MySQL: 3306
```

I tried some extra .htaccess file directives reading some forums but none works in my situation:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

My current (unmodified) .htaccess file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /testblog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /testblog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I didn't found the problem. Anyway, the only difference between the plugin test page and my postman request is the "Cookie" header. If I copied the Cookie Header to my postman request this request works. Any idea? I am really confused about this.

Comment: After installing that plugin, did you enable access to that plugin in their settings? Also, you say that you installed that plugin to enable API access, but WordPress has a native API already, that plugin just adds additional authentication. The native API also supports authentication via [application passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/)

Comment: Yes, the plugin is enabled after the installation. I know that I can use the cookie authentication (default for Wordpress REST API) but I want use Basic http auth (Sorry if I eplained bad, english is not my first language).

Comment: I have the same error, did everything as you